# VNC Server in Client Web Browser?

Tags: browser, vnc, remote-assistance

I see a lot of solutions such as noVNC, Flashlight VNC, etc, that implement a VNC *client* in the web browser, but are there any solutions that implement a VNC *server* in the browser, client-side, without an install?

Basically, I'd love to do browser-to-browser remote support. I was wondering if this is possible since half of the solution (the VNC client) is already there...

For clarification: The VNC would run in the browser (any browser), without an install, on the computer of the user needing assistance. The VNC client would run in the browser, without an install, on the computer of the person giving support.

Answer (score 0):

If you both are running the Chrome web-browser, check out [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher).

> Access other computers or allow another user to access your computer securely over the Internet.
>
> Chrome Remote Desktop allows users to remotely access another computer through Chrome browser or a Chromebook.  Computers can be made available on an short-term basis for scenarios such as ad hoc remote support, or on a more long-term basis for remote access to your applications and files.  All connections are fully secured.
>
> Chrome Remote Desktop is fully cross-platform.  Provide remote assistance to Windows, Mac and Linux users, or access your Windows (XP and above) and Mac (OS X 10.6 and above) desktops at any time, all from the Chrome browser on virtually any device, including Chromebooks.

Comment: I was looking at that, but it's not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: You may want to add that into your question then.

Comment: To be cross-browser at that point, you'd need (**shudder**) java, which would be more hassle than just asking the user to install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).

Comment: I actually found something... GSVNCJ. I think I might use this as one option on the page and fall back to team viewer if they can't get it to work.